# Merge react app with react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack

I want to put React app files in the React Native app.

I used [React Native Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) to support React Native components in the React app.

Last step I want to put all files from React App folder to React Native App folder.

the difference is in Package.json

React Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

React Native Package.json:

```
{
    "name": "appname",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native": "0.47.1",
        "react-native-windows": "0.47.0-rc.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
        "jest": "20.0.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "rnpm-plugin-windows": "^0.2.7"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

So is it possible I can merge the two packages together?

Comment: I using now https://github.com/react-everywhere/re-start/tree/react-16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your native app you can use package.json from React Native, no need to merge. You don't need "react-dom" and similar libs in native app. If your components are all from React Native for Web, there will be no problem running them on native.

Comment: I want to merge so both native and web work not only native.

Comment: as you can see in scripts  "start" in the web is different than native

Comment: Than first problem you will find are different versions of react:  "react": "^15.6.1" and  "16.0.0-alpha.12", you can try run them both with 16-beta, seams React Native for Web supports it now https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/364 I haven't tried that. In my project I have different folders "app" (containing native app) and "web", both having different node_modules and share src files which are in "app" folder

Comment: About scripts, like "start", you can rename web one to "start-web"

Comment: thank you, one last question is the dependancies from react package will increase the android file app?

Comment: There will be only few of them that are just for web, like "react-dom" and react native will not import those at all, they will be just installed in node_modules,  but not used by react native, they will be used by react native for web. So this should not increase size of mobile builds.